# Rename eclipse viewpart on mouse click

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

I know how to programmatically rename a eclipse RCP IViewPart. It is by using setPartname() method. However I want to know if in-place editing of the view name on mouse-click on the view tab (like we usually do for excel spreadsheet tabs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for in-place editing of the view name.

Comment: thanks greg. This came up as a requirement for my application . However when I try visualise , this seems to be clumsy way. At last I implemented this by including a rename dialog in my application